# change uri of external pages in a content with htaccess http to https

Tags: http, https

We recently implemented ssl in our web blog, but the content already has tags like `img`  inside of it. The destination site doesn't have an ssl. Our page is a catalog like an unreliable site, and I want to change the uri of request of contents from http to https. For example:

Change the url from `www.page.com/images/example1.jpg` to `www.ourpage.com/images/example1.jpg`. But this inside of a content. I don't know if it is possible.

```
<p>content <img scr="http://www.page.com/images/example1.jpg" /> more content.... <a href="http://www.page2.com?id=xxxxx ">click here...</a></p>
```

To:

```
<p>content <img scr="https://www.ourpage.com/images/example1.jpg" /> more content.... <a href="https://www.ourpage.com?id=xxxxx ">click here...</a></p>
```

Comment: What you describe is not changing an HTTP url to an HTTPS url, it is changing one domain to another domain, which is very different.

Comment: yes, @RemyLebeau you're right. That´s what we want. But the protocol it has to be https (My mistake: I forgot include the "s" in the http address). We have a lot of content, so, we can't invest time in that because represent us cost. What do you think???